# Grabbing value and appending to textarea with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, textarea

I'm stuck!

I have this simple form:

```
<p><input type="text" name="hometown" id="hometown" size="22" /></p>
<p><textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea></p>
```

What I need is to **append** the input value from `#hometown` to textarea! It mustn't replace text already written there. In the best case, it'd just print at the end of whatever is written on ''submit'' click.

This is how far I've got with my Javascript, but nothing seems to work.

```
function addtxt(input) {
    var hometown = document.getElementById('hometown').value;
    var obj=document.getElementById(comment)
    var txt=document.createTextNode(lol)
    obj.appendChild(txt)
}
```

Comment: Please post the Javascript code, u have written?

Answer (score 3):

Textarea has `value` property to operate with its contents. Just use `+=` to append text:

```
document.getElementById("comment").value +=
    document.getElementById("hometown").value;
```

Comment: Wow thanks, this Javascript works, but not when I add this function OnClick of the submit button. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2307598 It depends how you use it. `submit` button by default should send the form data to the server. I'd use either simple `button` or "override" form `onsubmit` with `return false`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var oldval=$('#comment').val();
var newval=$('#hometown').val();
S('#comment').val(oldval+' '+newval);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example for you I've put on JSFiddle, using pure javascript and the onClick listener

http://jsfiddle.net/vyqWx/1/

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="hometown" id="hometown" size="22" />
<textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
<input type="submit" onClick="doMagic();">
```

**JS**

```
function doMagic(){    
    var homeTown = document.getElementById("hometown").value;    
    document.getElementById("comment").value += homeTown;
}
```